# How can i read messages from a ROSbag file?

Tags: ros, rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a bag file in which some are custom messages whereas others are string messages. How can i display the contents of the topics which have message of type strings (without converting it to a .csv file) ?[image: image description]

for example, From the attached image, how can i read the messages of the topic `/pnc/relative_carstatus`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288319/how-can-i-read-messages-from-a-rosbag-file-?/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-04-11

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kharkad](https://answers.ros.org/users/34550/kharkad/) on 2018-04-11**:
I do have a question for you, how do you convert a rosbag file into a csv file?
Anyway, why don't you use the `rosbag play` to play your bag file, and then in another terminal you just see the messages passing into the topic with `rostopic echo /pnc/relative_carstatus`?

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-04-11**:
Hi to convert a bag file to .csv format, use `rostopic echo /topicname -b bagFileName.bag -p > file.csv`
And to the second part, I only have a bag file and when i play it, unfortunately no new nodes are created and no topics as well. That is why i cannot echo any topic.

**Comment by [kharkad](https://answers.ros.org/users/34550/kharkad/) on 2018-04-11**:
Personally, whenever I use rosbag I start all nodes manually, and then play the bad file to publish on the wanted topics. I don't think rosbag starts nodes.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-12**:
@aakash_sehgal please don't use an image to display text. Images are not searchable and people cannot copy and paste the text from the image. See http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Do

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-04-12**:
@kharkad how do you start all the nodes manually when you receive a bag file from someone else ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
I am confused: @aakash_sehgal: which nodes are you talking about? `rosbag` publishes msgs *as if* the original nodes were running. `rosbag` does not need the original nodes. If you're referring to "the rest" of the application (ie: consumers of msgs), that would be something else.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-04-12**:
@gvdhoorn yes, that is correct. I wanted to reply to @kharkad 's previous comment and then realised that `rosbag` do not requires original nodes.
Question : that means just by playing a bagfile i cannot access the messages. am i right ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
You can, as long as the system on which you are playing the bag has the necessary msgs. `rostopic echo` should be able to show msg content though, just as it would with 'normal' publications.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-04-12**:
@gvdhoorn Ohh yes... i was making some very basic mistake. thanks for it.
Another related question : when i echo the topic, i get `data : !! Binary |` and some unreadable characters below. This is the same when i visualize the topics in `rqt_bag`. can i convert these ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
This would seem to be a new question. It would be better to post a new one, provided no-one has answered this before (use google: `rostopic echo data binary site:answers.ros.org`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use Rosbag API to access messages using a simple script

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API#cpp_api

---

Originally posted by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) with karma: 225 on 2018-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-12**:
Can you please update your question with a minimum working example?

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-04-12**:
@zainmehdi is it possible that i can execute this script in the terminal or do i need to specifically put this in the bagfiles directory and then execute it ?

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-04-12**:
@jayess ill try and do that and next time will take care about the image with text.

**Comment by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on 2018-04-29**:
Sorry for the late response. I hope your problem has been resolved. and to answer your question yes you can execute it like a normal script

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently wrote `ros_readbagfile`. You can use it like this:

```
ros_readbagfile <mybagfile.bag> [topic1] [topic2] [topic3] [...] [topic1000]
```

I wrote a tutorial for it too, here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/reading%20msgs%20from%20a%20bag%20file

See the tutorial for full instructions.

Thanks to this answer for getting me started: https://answers.ros.org/question/240829/filter-out-messages-from-a-ros-bag/?answer=240861#post-id-240861.

See also: https://answers.ros.org/question/240829/filter-out-messages-from-a-ros-bag/?answer=355983#post-id-355983

---

Originally posted by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) with karma: 171 on 2020-08-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephen Montgomery-Smith](https://answers.ros.org/users/53461/stephen-montgomery-smith/) on 2020-12-07**:
BTW, it is only a very few changes to get it to work with python3.  Important to noetic users.  I don't know how to contact you.  I am at stephen@missouri.edu

**Comment by [eRCaGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52105/ercaguy/) on 2021-09-21**:
@Stephen Montgomery-Smith, see my latest version of the code here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/ros_readbagfile.py. I upgraded it to Python3 a while back. Please ensure it works with Python3 now. I've also updated the ROS tutorial linked-to in my answer.